# jquery find element's position

Tags: jquery, element, position

```
<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>element</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>val</li>
</ul>
```

how can i get the position in the `ul` of the clicked `li` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this will do it for you:

```
$("li").click(function () {

   alert($(this).index());

});
```

Note that the index() function returns the index of the item in the jquery collection.  If you have multiple lists on the page, make sure your selector only selects the list items that you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    alert(   $(this).parent().find('li').index(this)  );
});
```

[Reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index)

I only tested with one `<ul>`. You'll need to `.each` if you're doing this on multiple `<ul>`s.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with index() http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index