# This may seem simple but I cant find the function needed in the jquery API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<ul>` that has some `<li>`s in it, I made it so when I click on one of them it changes the class to "curent-menu-item" but I want to also get the order of the `<li>`.

Example of what I want:

```
<ul>
    <li>first item</li>
    <li>first item</li> //I click this and I want to return the value 2 (or 1, I still dont really udnerstand when numerotating starts from 0 and when it starts from 1)
    <li>first item</li>
    <li>first item</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery find element's position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096212/jquery-find-elements-position)

Comment: Thank you! It seems like it will do just what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$("li").click(function () {
    alert($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/248/)

Comment: I had to wait 15 minutes to mark it and I was busy working. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index()` to get the index and use `addClass("class_name")` to change/add new css to the selected `<li>`

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $index = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass("curent-menu-item");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already did the adding class part, all I needed was to know which was the index of the item.